# Redis and Asp.Net session state - Timeouts with Eval

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis, asp.net-session

Sporadically I get 100 to 200 redis timeout exceptions. Because i use sessions on redis (via the official MS package) these become "500s"/yellow-screen-of-death to the client.

Investigating those timeouts using application insights, i found that the root cause are some "Eval" commands. I used the term "some" because the `keyHashSlot` reported on the exception message varies.

The exception also reports IOCP and Worker threads available (min is 100 and there are usually more than 10 free)

So, how can i dive even deeper and figure out why those Evals are dimming out? Are they timing out because of their content (the script that it's been executed)? or they are wasting too much time on the queue?

Comment: You can use `MONITOR` on redis client, and `SCRIPT DEBUG YES` to inspect your Lua scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at this? https://gist.github.com/JonCole/db0e90bedeb3fc4823c2#file-diagnoserediserrors-clientside-md.

Especially, the threadpool throttling bit: https://gist.github.com/JonCole/db0e90bedeb3fc4823c2#burst-of-traffic

Could you be experiencing high CPU on your client or threadpool throttling?

Comment: Yes, and my thread pool is being monitored accordantly to that code... currently set to 100, i see very few negative values, and when i do, it's averagely not more than -5/-10... my problems do not seem to be correlated to requests bursts also... i was having a slow morning when all the sudden 200 errors over 25 min period...

Comment: Can you send an email to azurecache@microsoft.com? Answers to the following questions would help (https://gist.github.com/JonCole/132b255425268459ec95#file-supportquestionnaire-md). With this info, we can take a look to see if there are any issues you might be facing on the server side.

Also, can you share all those 200 errors that you received?